# How do I add localForage to my web app without using a packing manager

Tags: javascript, localforage

Hey I need to add localForage to my web app without using Yarn, NPM, bower or any other package managers. How would I add the api organically. I am using ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/localForage/localForage):

> Download the [latest localForage from GitHub](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/releases/), or install with npm:

and

> To use localForage, just drop a single JavaScript file into your page:
>
> ```
> <script src="localforage/dist/localforage.js"></script>
> <script>localforage.getItem('something', myCallback);</script>
> ```